# Faded Color Prints

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, print-design

When I print from Photoshop, Indesign, Illustrator, etc. the colors are completely washed out. When I print from a PDF or from the web, they look fine. Anyone know anything?

Print Settings:

[image: Photoshop Print Settings]

Printed Results:

[image: Printed Results]

Using Dell C1765. Ink cartridges are all good.

Comment: What are your settings for when you print from an Adobe application?

Comment: Sounds like you have an issue with color Management. Check the documentation / support at https://helpx.adobe.com/

Comment: @AndrewH Print Settings — http://imgur.com/a/MyQHH

Comment: @AndrewH Printed Images — http://imgur.com/a/dqVlN